# Calling a kernel-level function faster that clock()

Tags: linux, timeout, kernel, solaris, clock

I've written a kernel-level function under `unix` module which samples system load. I'm calling my sample function in `clock()` under `clock.c` to take snapshots of the system load at every clock (e.g. every 10ms on my system). Is there any other place that I can call my sampling function more frequent that `clock()`? (e.g. every 1ms). Can `timeout` interface be helpful? If so, how?

*OS: Solaris 11 but advice on linux will also help*

Comment: Post your code.  Solaris provides `gethrtime()`, which claims to provide nanosecond resolution.  That may be useful depending on how you've implemented what you've failed to describe.

Comment: The [Dtrace profile provider](http://dtrace.org/guide/chp-profile.html) can provide higher resolution without modifying any kernel code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `nanosleep()` and call it recursively with a proper use of `fork()` to avoid blocking.

Answer (score 0):

In linux kernel, `hrtimer` maybe meet your goal.